# Correctly create a .NET class with a JSON schema

Tags: c#, json, class, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema mae with http://json-schema.org/

I'm trying to convert it in a class with some automatic tools or also via C# code, to avoid the manual work.
Let's say this is my input JSON:

```
{
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title":"test Schema",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "code":{
         "type":"string",
         "description":"..."
      },
      "success":{
         "type":"integer",
         "minimum":0,
         "maximum":1,
         "description":"..."
      },
      "status":{
         "type":"string",
         "enum":[
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
         ],
         "description":""
      },
      "quantity":{
         "type":"number",
         "minimum":0,
         "description":"..."
      },
      "utcTimestamp":{
         "type":"string",
         "format":"date-time",
         "description":"..."
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "code",
      "success",
      "status",
      "quantity",
      "utcTimestamp"
   ]
}
```

I wrote a simple program to generate a C# class from this using NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp:

```
using NJsonSchema;
using NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp;
using System.IO;
namespace JsonToClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("input.json");
            var schemaFromFile = JsonSchema.FromSampleJson(json);
            var classGenerator = new CSharpGenerator(schemaFromFile, new CSharpGeneratorSettings
            {
                ClassStyle = CSharpClassStyle.Poco
            });
            var codeFile = classGenerator.GenerateFile();
            File.WriteAllText("output.cs", codeFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NJsonSchema v10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0) (http://NJsonSchema.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------

namespace MyNamespace
{
    #pragma warning disable // Disable all warnings

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Properties 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("code", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Code Code { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("success", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Success Success { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("status", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("quantity", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Success Quantity { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("utcTimestamp", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public UtcTimestamp UtcTimestamp { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Code 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("type", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Success 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("type", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("minimum", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int Minimum { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("maximum", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int Maximum { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Status 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("type", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("enum", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string> Enum { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class UtcTimestamp 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("type", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("format", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Format { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Anonymous 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("$schema", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Schema { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("title", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("type", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("properties", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("required", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string> Required { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

Not exactly what I expected... For example, the first attribute must be a string called code, but here it is created a code attribute of Code type with a lot of useless stuff inside, as you can see.

Then, I'd like to like an int status, enum status, decimal/float quantity and utcTimestamp string... is it possible? How? Am I making some mistakes?

I tested also the Visual Studio – -> Edit — > Paste Special — > Paste JSON as Classes, but the result is the same.

Comment: I think your output is more correct than you realize. "Code" is indeed an object, which should be represented by a class with two string properties - "type" and "description". I cannot speak to the dictionary property, however.

Comment: It looks like `AdditionalProperties` is likely being added as a "catch-all" for those properties which may be in the JSON that the model doesn't recognize.  There *may* be a setting to exclude this if you don't want it.

Comment: @aardvark I don't think so... for example, for the first one, I need a string called "code"... type and description are not needed..

Comment: Well, then your JSON is not correct. Your JSON describes an object which contains an object called "properties", who has a property called "code", which is also an object.

Comment: Unfortunately, this json is what I got bundled with the documentation. Anyway, solution found: write manually the class... yeah!

Comment: It's been a while, but I think a bit of clarification could help. What you have is a JSON schema whereas `FromSampleJson` expects a JSON file. The second example from the accepted answer will work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate schema from json file:

```cs
var schemaFromFile = JsonSchema.FromSampleJson(json)
```

To create schema from json-schema file:

```cs
var schema = await JsonSchema.FromFileAsync(jsonSchemaFilePath)
```